# What are the changes in Akka.NET Cluster 1.0.8 and 1.1.1

Tags: akka.net, akka.net-cluster

I have an AKKA.NET Cluster which works while using AKKA.NET Cluster 1.0.8 Version and its relevant dependencies. The same Cluster while using Version 1.1.1 does not work. The Cluster is formed locally, but remote machines are not able to discover the cluster. This local cluster works with 1.1.1 also. Could this be a network issue or am I doing something wrong?

Here is the Akka Config Section of the Web.Config. This same config works on 1.0.8 but not on 1.1.1

```
<akka>
    <hocon>
      <![CDATA[
          akka {
            actor {
              provider = "Akka.Cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider, Akka.Cluster"       
                 }

            remote {
              log-remote-lifecycle-events = DEBUG
              helios.tcp {
                hostname = "10.221.50.137"
                port = 8085
              }
            }

            cluster {
            seed-nodes = ["akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@10.221.50.137:8085"]
          }
          }
      ]]>
    </hocon>
  </akka>
```

Is there Any API Changes or any configuration Changes in HOCON?
Any help Appreciated. Thanks!

**[Edit: 1]** This is the Error i am getting
[image]

**[Edit: 2]**
The Gist link for the logs https://gist.github.com/yashu2203/21e84af600cc3198961c0a6fe0300bb9

Comment: Could you provide some more description? What errors are logged i.e? It's possible, that error is related more to some version of Helios dependency than to Akka.Remote itself.

Comment: I get an error AssociationException: "Tried to Associate with an Invalid Address"
Eventhough this same address and port works for 1.0.8 version.

Comment: First and foremost, are both nodes running the same versions of both pieces of software? That's a pretty critical piece of information when debugging a networked issue. Second: if it works locally but not remotely then this is an environmental issue most likely. Double check that: every port / IP combination is free and that all firewall rules are open.

Comment: We also have detailed notes for each release: https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/releases

Comment: Both are running Akka 1.1.1 and the issue is persisting. But by Changing them back to 1.0.8, it works.
Also, A nomal node in 1.1.1 is getting connected to a seed node in 1.0.8.

Comment: @Aaronontheweb i have figured it out. Symantec Endpoint Protection was the problem. The cluster formed after disabling it. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Okay, now the question here is how did previous version of Akka i.e v1.0.8 bypassed  the security(Symantec Endpoint Protection).